# How to return specific attributes from a stream method

Tags: java, oop, java-stream

I made a method in my item class which filters through my Array list items which has less than 2 quantities.

The method is returning all the attributes of that item when I want only its name and price.

I'm stuck on what needs to be change in my method

```
public static List<item>  findquantity(List<item> items) { 
    return items.stream()
      .filter(item -> item.getquantity()< 2)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I am calling the method in my main as

```
System.out.println(item.findquantity(itemDatabase));
```

Comment: "The method is returning all the attributes of that item when I want only its name and price."
The method is returning a list of Items, maybe you want it to return something else, what do you mean by " I want only its name and price.", is it an array of two string? a pair object? some custom object?

Comment: You need a `.map(item -> objectOnlyContainingNameAndPrice)` after filtering, i.e. create a class that only holds name and price and create instances by using item values.

Comment: On a side note: please stick to the Java naming conventions, i.e. your class should be named `Item`. Otherwise the class name could be mixed up with the instance name `item`.

Comment: my method returns the filtered item less than 2 quantity with all its attributes such as item name,item price,item quantity,item id.

i want it to only return the name and price

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change the return type of `findQuantity` to `Map<String, Double>` instead of `List<Item>`,  you can use `Collectors.toMap()` to return only `name` and `price` :

```
public static Map<String, Double>  findQuantity(List<Item> items) { 
    return items.stream().filter(item -> item.getQuantity() < 2)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getName, Item::getPrice));
}
```

A better way is to create a custom object that holds the values as referred in the comments by @Thomas. Should be something like this:

```
items.stream().filter(item -> item.getQuantity() < 2).map(i -> new CustomItem(i.getName(), i.getPrice()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thay custom object looks like a nice use case for a `record`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
First you have to make a class that contain two fields, price and name, example:

```
   Class Price{
    String name;
    BigDecimal price;// I don't Know is your quantity is int, Double or Float
    //Any other property that you need
    
    //Constructor
    //Getter & Setter
    }
```

And Modifique your Mehtod:

```
   public static List<Price>  findquantity(List<item> items) {

List<Price> lstPrice = new ArrayList<>();
items.stream().filter(it -> it.getquantity()< 2).map((vals) -> {
            Price item = new Price();
            item.setName(vals.getName());
            item.setPrice(vals.getquantity()); 
            //set any other property that you need           
            return item;
        }).forEachOrdered((item) -> {
            lstPrice.add(item);
        });
 return lstPrice;
}
```

That's all, I hope that help you